# Trouble of Action Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I develop a new web-application with Ruby on Rails and introduce "devise" gem to register and configure user accounts.Now, we face "not sending a configuration email problem".This program is finished on web properly ,but a configuration e-mail is not sent, then a user cannot log in this application.I'd like to know how to solve this problem.

Following is a console message during the application is running.(Secret password is masked.)

```html
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-15 18:32:41 +0900
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "user"=>{"email"=>"aaaaa@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14
 User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM ｀users｀ WHERE ｀users｀.｀email｀ = BINARY 'aaaaa@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
 ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14
 User Create (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO ｀users｀ (｀email｀, ｀encrypted_password｀, ｀confirmation_token｀, ｀confirmation_sent_at｀, ｀created_at｀, ｀updated_at｀) VALUES ('aaaaa@gmail.com', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz', '2018-07-15 09:32:41', '2018-07-15 09:32:41', '2018-07-15 09:32:41')
 ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14
  (3.9ms)  COMMIT
 ↳ app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:14
 Rendering users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
 Rendered users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.8ms)
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 1861ms (ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-15 18:32:43 +0900
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
 Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
 Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 29ms (Views: 28.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Add to that, this configuration system uses a *Gmail* client. I got a password in order to run this program and registered it and I have not any changes on 'users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb' from its default file.

This is the /app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb file.

```html
# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  #GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  #POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  #GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    super
  end

  #PUT /resource
  def update
    super
  end

  #DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    super
  end

  #GET /resource/cancel
  #Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  #in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  #cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  #removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    super
  end

  protected

 # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  end

 # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  end

 # The path used after sign up.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
  end

 # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super(resource)
  end
end
```

I'm looking forward to hear lots of advice.

Comment: First make sure that you have the working smtp settings. Try to send one mail using the same smtp settings from the console level

Comment: @Navin Thank you for replying. I checked it by rails console and found that credential file has errors.